# Python regex: Extract volume (mL) from strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string to extract volume (match only ml, not mg/ml)

```
test = [
"10ML", # 10
"10 ML", # 10
"10.5ML", # 10.5
"1MG/1ML", # [] not match
"1MG/10ML", # [] not match
"10MG/0.5ML", # [] not match
"   10ML and 15ML  ", # 10, 15
"LODEXA (DEXAMETHASONE) 5 MG/ML INJECTION", # []
"NSS.0.9% 1000 ML (PLASTIC BAG)", # 1000
"110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML", # 10
]
```

Here is my current pattern and result.

```
pattern = re.compile("(?<!\/)([0-9]*[.]*[0-9]+)\s*ML(?![\/A-z])")

for i, s in enumerate(test):
    print(test[i], '>>' , pattern.findall(s))

10ML >> ['10']
10 ML >> ['10']
10.5ML >> ['10.5']
1MG/1ML >> []
1MG/10ML >> ['0'] # Wrong []
10MG/0.5ML >> ['.5'] # Wrong []
   10ML and 15ML   >> ['10', '15']
LODEXA (DEXAMETHASONE) 5 MG/ML INJECTION >> []
NSS.0.9% 1000 ML (PLASTIC BAG) >> ['1000']
110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML >> ['10', '30'] # Wrong ['10']
```

As you can see,
I got the wrong results from `["1MG/10ML", "10MG/0.5ML", "110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML"]`. It should be `[[], [], ['10']`.

I have tried to fix my pattern but still can't figure it out. Please help me correct my pattern. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<![/\d])(?<!\d[.-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*ML\b(?!/)
```

See the [Python regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eu7YtY/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<![/\d])` - no `/` or digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!\d[.-])` - no digit + `.` or `-` allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits, and an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `ML\b` - `ML` as a whole word
- `(?!/)` - no `/` allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6JJjh3):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<![/\d])(?<!\d[.-])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*ML\b(?!/)', re.A)
test = ["10ML", "10 ML", "10.5ML", "1MG/1ML", "1MG/10ML", "10MG/0.5ML", "   10ML and 15ML  ",
"LODEXA (DEXAMETHASONE) 5 MG/ML INJECTION", "NSS.0.9% 1000 ML (PLASTIC BAG)", 
"110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML"]
for i, s in enumerate(test):
    print(test[i], '>>' , pattern.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
10ML >> ['10']
10 ML >> ['10']
10.5ML >> ['10.5']
1MG/1ML >> []
1MG/10ML >> []
10MG/0.5ML >> []
   10ML and 15ML   >> ['10', '15']
LODEXA (DEXAMETHASONE) 5 MG/ML INJECTION >> []
NSS.0.9% 1000 ML (PLASTIC BAG) >> ['1000']
110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML >> ['10']
```

Comment: Thank you! Your pattern covers all of my string. You also notice that I put `(?!)` to avoid `/` after ML, although my examples don't have it.

Answer (score 3):

See [this RegExr](https://regexr.com/5t369) link for details about the components of the following regex expression.

```
import re

test = [
    "10ML", # 10
    "10 ML", # 10
    "10.5ML", # 10.5
    "1MG/1ML", # [] not match
    "1MG/10ML", # [] not match
    "10MG/0.5ML", # [] not match
    "   10ML and 15ML  ", # 10, 15
    "LODEXA (DEXAMETHASONE) 5 MG/ML INJECTION", # []
    "NSS.0.9% 1000 ML (PLASTIC BAG)", # 1000
    "110 MLM HIDRASEC (RACECADOTIL)10 ML POWDER FOR 1-30 ML", # 10
]

for s in test:
    re.findall(r'(?<![\-\/])(\d+(?:\.?\d+)) *ML\b', s)
```

Output

```
['10']
['10']
['10.5']
[]
[]
[]
['10', '15']
[]
['1000']
['10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one maybe easier to read:

```
(?<![/\d-])(\d+\.*\d+)\s*ML\b
```